# grep utf8/unicode support/ u modifier

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-8, grep

I'm trying to validate vtt files for a particular format. The regex is functional but UTF8 characters are causing issues. I tried using `(?u)` with no luck

The regex I'm using is:

```
grep -P '(?m)^(\d+:\d+[.]\d+\s*-->\s*\d+:\d+[.]\d+|\s*[\w\s]+)|^\s*$' . -r -v
```

The `u` flag allows the regex to work as expected here, https://regex101.com/r/21HW2A/1, but I can't find a way to do that in `grep`. Do I need to swap the `\w` to all allowed alphanumeric chars or can the `u` modifier be used in `grep` somehow?

Comment: I don't think grep supports Unicode at all. You should probably switch to a tool that is Unicode-aware. Maybe Python could be an option?

Comment: I found one solution, use `\p{L}` in place of `\w`. Not sure if there is a unicode flag still though.

Comment: That would be the canonical solution in a regex that runs atop a Unicode-aware tool. Does it work with your version of grep?

Comment: Yes, I'm running AWS Linux 2.0, `GNU grep 2.20`.

Comment: Well then you have your solution and I have learned something. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `\w` can be converted to `\p{L}` which doesn't require the `u` modifier for unicode support.

Full solution:

```
grep -P '(?m)^(\d+:\d+[.]\d+\s*-->\s*\d+:\d+[.]\d+|\s*[\p{L}\s]+)|^\s*$' . -r -v
```